# Issue with relative date formats in php

Tags: php, datetime

I'm ussing a function which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760262/php-adding-months-to-a-date-while-not-exceeding-the-last-day-of-the-month) to add months to a date considering that some months have less days than others.

```
    function addMonths($date_str, $months){
        $date = new DateTime($date_str);
        $start_day = $date->format('j');
 var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d'));
        $date->modify("+{$months} month");
        $end_day = $date->format('j');
        var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d'));
        if ($start_day != $end_day)
            $date->modify('last day of last month');
        var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d'));die();
        return $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```

Since the function is not working as expected I dumped some variables to see what's going on. Let's try the following:

```
addMonths('2012-05-31',1)
```

And I'm getting the following wrong output:

```
string(10) "2012-05-31" string(10) "2012-07-01" string(10) "2012-05-31"
```

As you can see when I add a month to input date I get "2012-07-01" but then the conditional is met and I should get the last day of June which is the previous month of July and not May. I don't know what's happening, can you help me?

Comment: which php version do you use? the last dump returns `2012-06-30` for me.

Comment: 5.2.9, AFAIK modify method works with this version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP had a [bug with DateTime relative formats](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53741) until PHP 5.2.17

Try this instead:

```
<?php
function addMonths($date_str, $months) {
  $date      = new DateTime($date_str);
  $start_day = $date->format('j');

  $date->modify("+{$months} month");
  $end_day = $date->format('j');

  if ($start_day != $end_day) {
    $date->modify('last day');
  }

  return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo addMonths('2012-05-31', 1);
```

I don't have such an old version of PHP here but I think it can handle `last day` in this version.

For me it returns:

```
2012-06-30
```

Comment: Great it also works for my version, however I will update my php version since this doesn't work for leap years. Thanks

Comment: Sure no problem. And yes, I *highly* recommend to update your PHP version!

Comment: If you read the bug report it actually isn't a bug. I don't believe all of the relative time formats work prior to 5.3. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your code, and following is my output on PHP 5.3.3:

```
string(10) "2012-05-31"
string(10) "2012-07-01"
string(10) "2012-06-30"
```

Comment: Don't know if is my php version, I'm using 5.2.9

Comment: It would seem that this is a bug in your PHP version.  See @DanLee's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function add_month($format , $date , $months_to_add ){
        return date($format, strtotime("$date +$months_to_add month"));
}
```

I am using this. You can try this one.