# Why am I getting this Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string error?

Tags: php, html, date, datetime, string-formatting

I saw this code here on stack overflow

```
    function add($date_str, ${
    $date = new DateTime($date_str);
    $start_day = $date->format('j');

    $date->modify("+{$months} month");
    $end_day = $date->format('j');

    if ($start_day != $end_day)
        $date->modify('last day of last month');

    return $date;
}

$result = add('2011-01-28', 1);  // 2011-02-28
$result = add('2011-01-31', 3);  // 2011-04-30
```

Which increments the date but does not exceed the last day of the month. But when i try to run the function using

`$dues=add('2011-01-28', 1); echo $dues;`

It returns an "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string" error? But it seems that it works for other people.

[Original link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760262/php-adding-months-to-a-date-while-not-exceeding-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: There is syntax error in the first row: `function add($date_str, ${`. Missing second var name and bracket.

Answer (score 0):

The first row of your code has to be:

```
function add($date_str, $months) {
```

You have there syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Format of function is not right. Use the code below

```
function add($date_str, $months){
    $date = new DateTime($date_str);
    $start_day = $date->format('j');

    $date->modify("+{$months} month");
    $end_day = $date->format('j');

    if ($start_day != $end_day)
        $date->modify('last day of last month');

    return $date;
}

$result = add('2011-01-28', 1);  // 2011-02-28
$result = add('2011-01-31', 3);  // 2011-04-30
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score -3):

All I had to do was to use  `$dues->format('Y-m-d')`