# Not a duplicate : How to display date of next 6 months in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am working on loan slider calculation in which if user select any date from drop down then i have to show the ext 6 months date.
for ex: if user selects the date "5"
then next 6 dates would be which are i am getting now:

```
1 5th Dec 2017
2 5th Jan 2018
3 5th Feb 2018
4 5th Mar 2018
5 5th Apr 2018
6 5th May 2018
```

But if user selects the `"30" or "31"` from the drop down then it skips the February month.

Please Help!!!!

Comment: That is special case, you need to explicitly write the code for those dates and don't forget to consider leap year case too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760262/php-adding-months-to-a-date-while-not-exceeding-the-last-day-of-the-month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Adding months to a date, while not exceeding the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760262/php-adding-months-to-a-date-while-not-exceeding-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: Not a duplicate issue because i tried that example it's not working in my case....

Comment: Uhm, but that's precisely what the duplicate is about. That none of the examples worked is left without proof in your question here. And it's not less of a duplicate even if none of the answers are complete yet.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this function:

```
    function add($date_str, $months)
    {
        $date = new DateTime($date_str);


        $start_day = $date->format('j');


        for($i=1;i<=$months;$i++)
{ 
        $date->modify("+{$i} month");


        $end_day = $date->format('j');

        if ($start_day != $end_day)
        {

            $date->modify('last day of last month');
        }

        echo  $date;
    }
    }
```

Call add(date,6);