# Custom post type upcoming events for week and next month

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$todayDate = date('m/d/Y');
$futureDate = strtotime ( '+7 days' , strtotime ( $todayDate ) ) ;
$futureDate = date ( 'm/d/Y' , $futureDate );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'event_category' => 'events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => $futureDate,
        )
        ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

I want to show the upcoming events for the next week or next month. I have this args array set but still giving me the post of yesterday's and not sorted as how i wanted. Also, how to get rid of yesterday's post in my query..

Comment: Your args array does not use `$todayDate` as a criteria. It's only using the `$futureDate` which is seven days in the future. Is this limiting your args to search for events that are before this date which includes before today?

Comment: I wanted to limit events/posts from today to seven days in the future and get rid of past events (yesterday's event/post) that is still displaying. @mcv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want your args to limit events that fall between today and the future date, where future date is today +7 days.

Hence you want to modify your args to include another array with the following parameters. Try this:

```
//event_date >= $todayDate
//event_date <= $futureDate

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'event_category' => 'events',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => $todayDate,
        ),
        array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '<=',
        'value' => $futureDate,
        ), 
        ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

Comment: For the 'next month' event would be `'+1 month'` or `'+30 days'` right?

Comment: That sounds correct but there might be a case with February. [This question was asked and answered will explain more if you need more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760262/php-adding-months-to-a-date-while-not-exceeding-the-last-day-of-the-month)